# Why is my promise chain not resolving?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I am just getting into using promises.  I wrote this method in my VUE component.  Debugging it, the api is definately returning data and is getting to the commented line.

When the function returns it never makes it to the original callers .then method.  Neither of the alerts i setup are working.

Am I structuring my promise chain wrong or something?

Entrance function

```
mounted() {
        PersonApi.Get(this.personId).then((response) => {
            alert('done');
            this.person = response;
            this.loading = false;
        }).catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
```

Library that makes the call

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default class PersonApi {
    private static ResolveApiResponse(response: any): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (response.errors != undefined && response.errors.length > 0) {
                return Promise.reject(response.errors);
            }

            return Promise.resolve(response.Data); // code is getting to this line
        });
    }

    public static Get(id: number): Promise<any> {
        return axios.get('/api/Person/' + id)
            .then((response: any) => {
                return PersonApi.ResolveApiResponse(response.data);
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Fixed code

Updated to this

```
private static ResolveApiResponse(response: any): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (response.errors != undefined && response.errors.length > 0) {
                resolve(response.errors);
            }

            resolve(response.Data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: When resolving a promise, call `resolve` instead of `Promise.resolve`, same goes for the reject state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resolving a promise, you should call the passed resolv function object, instead of making a new promise using the `Promise.resolve` function

```
new Promise((resolv, reject) => {
    resolve('hello world'); // Resolv the promise
    Promise.resolve('Hello World'); // This makes a new promise that is directly resolved
})
```

Normally, `Promise.resolve` should only be used when inside an api, you want to return a precached, or returning a mocked calculation .